# Как с помощью Cordova сделать iOS build для iPhone

Tags: ios, phonegap, cordova

Я сделал следующее:

1. Установил вирт. машину Max OS X.
2. На ней установил xcode, cordova, phonegap.
3. Добавил в своем проекте платформу ios - сработало.
4. Ввел команду build ios - выполнено успешно.
5. Сделал джейлбрейк своего 4-го айфона и установил Cydia, AppSynch

А дальше не знаю что делать. Мне кордова не выдает готового ipa файла, в папке `ios/build` какой-то бардак. Помогите разобраться плиз, что сделать, чтобы запустить приложение на `iOS` девайсе с помощью кордовы?

Comment: `cordova run ios --device` не работает?

Answer (score 2):

Я делаю так

```
ionic build ios
```

После завершения билда, открываю XCode, и указываю путь до папки с проектом, к примеру:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/WORK/yourApp/platforms/ios
```

Дальше просто вместо эмулятора выбираю подключенный девайс (iphone 4 jb) через usb и XCode заливает на телефон приложение.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько знаю запустить приложение можно только с помощью xCode, а cordova помогает собрать проект под выбранную платформу

Подключите телефон, выберите устройство и выполните запуск приложения (если выполняется только компиляция то в схеме приложения поменяйте настройку см. документацию на сайте cordova)

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/index.html