# Как установить свое приложение на IOS в обход AppStore

Tags: ios, cordova, appstore, ionic

Разрабатываю мобильное приложение для внутреннего использования (склад компании). Приложение должно быть кроссплатформенным, решил воспользоваться Ionic / Cordova. Операторы склада должны устанавливать данное приложение на свои смартфоны.

Опыта разработки мобильных приложений нет, инструментов которыми воспользовался достаточно.

**Вопрос:**

Каким образом операторы могут установить приложение без его публикации на AppStore. В AppStore выкладывать смысла нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зарегистрироваться, оплатить годовой членский взнос разработчика Apple и установить приложение на телефон для тестирования/отладки минуя AppStore

Comment: У Ionic нет сервисов как у https://appery.io для "тестирования" приложения с устройства? Насколько мне известно регистрация достаточно затянутый процесс.

Comment: В случае регистрации в качестве разработчика, другие пользователи каким образом смогут получить доступ к приложению?

Comment: вот хороший ответ, но требуется jailbreak телефона: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475142/Как-с-помощью-cordova-сделать-ios-build-для-iphone?rq=1)  Если зарегистрироваться разработчиком, то Apple разрешает устанавливать приложение для теста на устройства прямо из x-code с полным функционалом - приложение будет работать на телефоне даже после окончания членства в разработчиках Apple

Comment: Сейчас пользуюсь для теста iphone 4 jailbreak и вполне доволен. Видимо это действительно единственный вариант. Либо же, всем выдать девайсы на android и не заморачиваться, но конечно это не идеальный выход из сложившейся ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

У Apple есть корпаративная программа. Это когда приложение распространяется только внутри компании.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать платформу ionic.io + приложение ionic view http://view.ionic.io/

- загружаете приложение
- ставите приложение
- высылаете инвайт

Есть ограничение - не все плагины, но основные работают http://docs.ionic.io/docs/view-usage

> The following is a list of plugins supported by View:
>
> com.brodysoft.sqlitePlugin 1.0.3 "Brodysoft SQLitePlugin"
> com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.3 "Keyboard"
> com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner 1.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"
> org.apache.cordova.battery-status 0.2.12 "Battery"
> org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.4 "Camera" org.apache.cordova.console
> 0.2.12 "Console" org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.13 "Device" org.apache.cordova.device-motion 0.2.11 "Device Motion"
> org.apache.cordova.device-orientation 0.3.10 "Device Orientation"
> org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.11 "Notification"
> org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.11 "Geolocation"
> org.apache.cordova.globalization 0.3.3 "Globalization"
> org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.14 "Network Information"
> org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.12 "Vibration" org.chromium.zip 1.0.0
> "Zip"

Answer (score 0):

- 1.Создаете проект Cordova

  2. Создаете аккаунт разработчика Apple Developer
  3. Добавляете через настройки- аккаунт - аккаунт созданный в пункте 2
  4. Выбираете проект, в пункте signing&capabilities ставите галочку automatic signing
  5. выбираете свой профиль, после чего сгенерируется сертификат автоматически
  6. подключаете через usb iPhone и выбираете его в списке девайсов(в списке с эмулторами)
  7. жмете на иконку play (build and run in current scheme)
  8. ваше Cordova приложение появляется на телефоне